# Sql server 2012 - management studio, no option "refresh intellisense cache"

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have got an big problem. 
I am sure that you have seen the problem "invalid column name" and solution "just click CTRL + SHIFT + R or Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache".
And there is my problem: **I don't have this option**. When I **use** combination "Ctrl shift r" my program do not answer.
I use *Sql server 2012 express* and *windows authetication*. 
Do you have any solution???

I just have: **Undo, Redo, cut, copy, paste, delete, select all, find and replace, go to..., navigate to... and bookmarks.**

Comment: If you go to "Tools >> Customise", then on the commands tab, choose "Edit" from the left hand list box, and the right hand list box scroll down to "Refresh Local Cache". Do you see this? Can you then drag this command to your edit menu?

Comment: I have been clicking Commands-> Menu Bar: Edit Intellisense and I there is Refresh local cache there. What should i click to drag this command to my edit menu??